# ProGuard leads to NullPointerException

Tags: android, build, proguard, minify, shrinkresources

When setting `minifyEnabled true` in my gradle I get a *NullPointerException* when starting my app:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.ae.formulaecalendar/de.ae.formulaecalendar.view.calendar.CalendarActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
   at de.ae.formulaecalendar.view.calendar.CalendarActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

While reading through StackOverflow I found some settings for the *proguard-rules.pro* file:

```
######### KEEP ANDROID SUPPORT V7 AND DESIGN
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

which didn't really solve this problem (but a previous NullPointerException).

Finally the important part of my gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

When I disbale `minifyEnabled` everthing works fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me. Keeping the classes did solve the null pointer exception? And can you please post the code of `CalendarActivity.onCreate()`?

Comment: Please make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Reaz Murshed: Before this NullPointerException occured there was a previous one caused by ProGuard which I could resolve with the posted proguard rules.  But these rules don't help with this NullPointerException and I don't know why. Sorry if it was unclear. I added the onCreate and the layout xml.

Comment: @m0skit0: I will try to make one

Comment: Proguard rules for common Android libraries [proguard-rules](https://gist.github.com/jemshit/767ab25a9670eb0083bafa65f8d786bb)

Answer (score 12):

It's likely that this happens, when serializing objects and the fields are not annotated by `@SerializedName("param")` (or similar)  and therefor can not be found.

For *debugging* it also helps to **temporarily** set `-keepnames class **` so that the class names are not obfuscated.

Comment: The debugging hint is helpful, showed me what was going wrong

Answer (score 8):

For me, adding lines (you may have other name for package where you put your POJO files):

```
-keep class [mypackagename].model.** { *; }
-keep class [mypackagename].datamodel.** { *; }
```

to `proguard.rules` worked perfectly, then options:

```
android
{
    ...

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled true 
            shrinkResources true

        }
    }
}
```

are set in `build.gradle` (Module: app)

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to keep the files provided from the libraries you included in your project. I'm sharing one of my `proguard-rules.pro` which might help you to understand.

```
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class com.github.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.** { *; }
-keep class junit.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
-keep class com.myproject.model.** { *; }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me it looks like it cannot find `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` or `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager` which is part of one of the libraries included in my project (`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'`). That's why I added `-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }` to my proguard rules, without any success.

Comment: You need to keep the class started with `com.android.` too. Check the list I've added. These are the usual classes you need to keep.

Comment: I solved it. It was a problem with `shrinkResources` in the gradle file. However, thank you for your help. I learned something about ProGuard.

Comment: This is way too loose of a rule set. You might as well turn proguard off entirely.

Answer (score 2):

most of the time the error because of android libs, try this

```
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
```