# By using Rxandroid getting null exception error in production but working in debug mode

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

Fetching data from server using retrofit. it's **working in debug mode but the app crashed in production.**

Code:-

```
compositeDisposable.add(Observable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                // Get each page in order.
                .concatMap(integer -> {
                    return apiInterface.postGetFeed(membersIds, lastFeedId);
                })
                // Take every result up to and including the one where the next page index is null.
                .takeUntil(result -> {
                    if(!result.getData().isEmpty())
                    lastFeedId = result.getData().get(result.getData().size() - 1).getId();
                    return result.getData().isEmpty();
                })
                .map(FeedResponse::getData)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Feed>>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onNext(List<Feed> feeds) {
                                   Log.d("feed", "" + feeds);
                                   memberDatabaseRepository.insertMemberList(feeds, lastFeedId);

                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                   //error getting here
                                   Log.d("feed", "error " + e.getMessage());

                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onComplete() {
                                   memberDatabaseRepository.getAllFeed(FeedFragment.this);
                                   shimmerViewContainerFeed.stopShimmer();
                                   shimmerViewContainerFeed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               }
                           }
                ));
```

logcat :

```
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16757/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer D/feed: error throw with null exception
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at c.e.a.a.g.r.a(Unknown Source:1)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at c.e.a.a.g.a.test(Unknown Source:4)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.e.d.r$a.a(Unknown Source:12)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.f.d.a(Unknown Source:60)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.e.d.b$b$a.a(Unknown Source:2)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at j.a.a.a$a.a(:1)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at j.a.a.c.b(:2)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.h.a(Unknown Source:10)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at j.a.a.a.b(Unknown Source:7)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.h.a(Unknown Source:10)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.e.d.b$b.d(Unknown Source:68)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.e.d.b$b.a(Unknown Source:35)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.e.d.l.b(Unknown Source:12)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.h.a(Unknown Source:10)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.113 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.e.d.b.b(:2)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.h.a(Unknown Source:10)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.e.d.r.b(Unknown Source:11)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.h.a(Unknown Source:10)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.e.d.j.b(Unknown Source:11)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.h.a(Unknown Source:10)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.e.d.q$b.run(Unknown Source:8)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.k$a.run(Unknown Source:9)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at e.b.e.g.i.call(:1)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.114 16757-16824/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-05-16 18:57:16.309 16757-16757/com.fitphilia.treadmill.trainer I/zygote64: Deoptimizing java.lang.String i.b.a.d.b.a(i.b.a.t) due to JIT inline cache
```

I tried with doing `shrinkResources false` and `minifyEnabled false` its working fine in production.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

but why it failed when I do `shrinkResources true` and `minifyEnabled true` in production.

Comment: looks like something is getting minified / excluded that shouldn't be and you need to experiment with excluding different things. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429895/proguard-leads-to-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This progaurd was missing

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
```

finally my production app is working fine .